# Compiling openssl-fips on Solaris10 x86

Tags: unix, openssl, autotools, solaris-10

I am currently trying to compile openssl-fips on a Solaris 10x86 machine, and I am having trouble linking to the fipscanister.o in my use of the library. Here is the problem that shows up when I attempt to link:

```
{PWD}/dist/openssl/bin/../lib/fipscanister.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

From what I have gathered when researching, the problem is this: the fipscanister.o was compiled as a 64 bit binary and it is linking to a 32 bit library. I have tried tracking the problem to my compilation of the openssl-fips. Here is the command that I believe is causing the issue:

```
./config fipscanisterbuild
```

This is the part of the output that I believe is messing it up:

```
Configuring for solaris64-x86_64-gcc
    no-camellia     [default]  OPENSSL_NO_CAMELLIA (skip dir)
    no-gmp          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_GMP (skip dir)
    no-krb5         [krb5-flavor not specified] OPENSSL_NO_KRB5
    no-mdc2         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MDC2 (skip dir)
    no-rc5          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)
    no-rfc3779      [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779 (skip dir)
    no-seed         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SEED (skip dir)
    no-zlib         [default]
    no-zlib-dynamic [default]
IsMK1MF=0
CC            =gcc
CFLAG         =-fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN   
               -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DMD32_REG_T=int
               -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM
EX_LIBS       =-lsocket -lnsl -ldl 
CPUID_OBJ     =x86_64cpuid.o
BN_ASM        =x86_64-gcc.o x86_64-mont.o
DES_ENC       =des_enc.o fcrypt_b.o
AES_ASM_OBJ   =aes-x86_64.o
BF_ENC        =bf_enc.o
CAST_ENC      =c_enc.o
RC4_ENC       =rc4-x86_64.o
RC5_ENC       =rc5_enc.o
MD5_OBJ_ASM   =md5-x86_64.o
SHA1_OBJ_ASM  =sha1-x86_64.o sha256-x86_64.o sha512-x86_64.o
RMD160_OBJ_ASM=
PROCESSOR     =
RANLIB        =/usr/ccs/bin/ranlib
ARFLAGS       =
PERL          =/opt/csw/bin/perl
SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG mode
DES_UNROLL used
DES_INT used
RC4_CHUNK is unsigned long
BF_PTR2 used
e_os2.h => include/openssl/e_os2.h
```

There are several things that I notice here:

1. fipscanisterbuild is autodetecting (incorrectly) that I am working on a solaris64-x86_64. Here is my uname -a:

   ```
   SunOS hostname 5.10 Generic_147441-01 i86pc i386 i86pc
   ```
2. CFLAG has the -m64 in it. This is forcing the fipscanister.o to compile as a 64 bit binary
3. At the end it says SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG mode

I have tried to force it to compile as a 32 bit binary with the following methods:

1. I first tried to use an env variable to force it to compile as a 32 bit binary with the -m32 flag

   ```
   export CC="gcc -m32"
   ```
2. I also tried to make the CFLAG use my own env variable with the command

   ```
   export CFLAG="gcc -m32"
   ```

   but to no avail.
3. I tried to make the configure use my architecture by changing the command

   ```
   ./config fipscanisterbuild
   ```

   to

   ```
   ./Configure solaris-x86-gcc
   ```

   and it seemed like it worked, at least it changed SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG mode to THIRTY_TWO_BIT mode. However when I compiled and tried to link to the fipscanister.o I got the same ELFCLASS64 error.

A side questions:

Why is my fipscanister option in ./config fipscanister recognizing my machine as an x86_64 when it is a 32 bit machine?

I am extremely stuck so it would be great if anyone could shed light on this very baffling problem.

Comment: Just guessing, but `i86pc` might be confusing the script. Try exporting `MACHINE`, `SYSTEM`, `BUILD` and `RELEASE`. `Configure` will use them to build the triplet if defined (rather than turning to `uname`). I think `MACHINE` is of interest and you might try, for example, i686. See the `config` script around line 50.

Comment: I just tried that but it unfortunately did not change how it was recognized. However looking at the config file I noticed that it is being seen as an x86_64 due to the fact that isalist is returning that it has amd64 in it. I thought isalist found the supported architectures of solaris, not what this particular machine supports? It is around line 608 of the config file if you are looking at it.

Comment: Are you *absolutely sure* that you're not running on a 64bit system? if `isainfo -k` tells you `amd64` then you're on a 64bit system (if `isalist` gives an `amd64` entry then it kind of implies this, although it's been ages since I've actually used 32bit Solaris)

Comment: isainfo -k returns amd64. However I am not sure how that can be. I built this vm myself and used an x86 iso and an x86 configuration. If I am really running 64 bit how come I am getting wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64? Does that mean that somewhere it is compiling 32bit instead and trying to link to the 64 bit fipscanister.o?

Comment: @Grindlemire - I asked a question on the OpenSSL User List about the `MACHINE` and `SYSTEM` tricks for Solaris. See [solaris-x86-cc or solaris-x86-gcc via MACHINE and SYSTEM exports](http://marc.info/?l=openssl-users&m=140493597310483&w=2). The tricks have worked in the past for me (I use it regularly for Android and iOS), so I'd be interesting in learning what the issue is with Solaris.

Comment: @Grindlemire - One more thing... Is Solaris 10/x86 a supported platform? You can see a list of them at [OpenSSL FIPS 140-2 Security Policy v 2.0.7](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140sp/140sp1747.pdf), *Chapter 2, Tested Configurations* (p. 9). It looks like the one Solaris 10/32-bit platform uses the SPARC-T3 (SPARCv9) processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more knob turning the the environmental variables, I was able to get the triplet `solaris-whatever-gcc` *with* 32-bit mode (`THIRTY_TWO_BIT mode`).

I'm not sure its expected, and it looks more like a bug in OpenSSL's configure system (especially the `SYSTEM="gcc"` part).

You still might need the `CC=gcc -m32` trick.

```
export KERNEL_BITS=32
export ARCH=x86

export MACHINE="solaris"
export RELAEASE="10"
export SYSTEM="gcc"
export BUILD="Solaris; Solaris 10; x86"

openssl-fips-2.0.5$ ./config 
Operating system: solaris-whatever-gcc
Auto Configuring fipsonly
Auto Configuring fipsonly
Configuring for gcc
Auto Configuring fipsonly
Configuring for gcc
    no-bf           [option]   OPENSSL_NO_BF (skip dir)
    no-camellia     [option]   OPENSSL_NO_CAMELLIA (skip dir)
    no-cast         [option]   OPENSSL_NO_CAST (skip dir)
    no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128 (skip dir)
    no-gmp          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_GMP (skip dir)
    no-idea         [option]   OPENSSL_NO_IDEA (skip dir)
    no-jpake        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_JPAKE (skip dir)
    no-krb5         [krb5-flavor not specified] OPENSSL_NO_KRB5
    no-md2          [option]   OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip dir)
    no-md5          [option]   OPENSSL_NO_MD5 (skip dir)
    no-mdc2         [option]   OPENSSL_NO_MDC2 (skip dir)
    no-rc2          [option]   OPENSSL_NO_RC2 (skip dir)
    no-rc4          [option]   OPENSSL_NO_RC4 (skip dir)
    no-rc5          [option]   OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)
    no-rfc3779      [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779 (skip dir)
    no-ripemd       [option]   OPENSSL_NO_RIPEMD (skip dir)
    no-seed         [option]   OPENSSL_NO_SEED (skip dir)
    no-srp          [forced]   OPENSSL_NO_SRP (skip dir)
    no-ssl2         [forced]   OPENSSL_NO_SSL2 (skip dir)
    no-ssl3         [forced]   OPENSSL_NO_SSL3 (skip dir)
    no-store        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_STORE (skip dir)
    no-tls1         [forced]   OPENSSL_NO_TLS1 (skip dir)
    no-tlsext       [forced]   OPENSSL_NO_TLSEXT (skip dir)
    no-zlib         [default] 
    no-zlib-dynamic [default] 
IsMK1MF=0
CC            =gcc
CFLAG         =-DOPENSSL_FIPSCANISTER -O3
EX_LIBS       =
CPUID_OBJ     =mem_clr.o
BN_ASM        =bn_asm.o
DES_ENC       =des_enc.o fcrypt_b.o
AES_ENC       =aes_core.o aes_cbc.o
BF_ENC        =bf_enc.o
CAST_ENC      =c_enc.o
RC4_ENC       =rc4_enc.o rc4_skey.o
RC5_ENC       =rc5_enc.o
MD5_OBJ_ASM   =
SHA1_OBJ_ASM  =
RMD160_OBJ_ASM=
CMLL_ENC      =camellia.o cmll_misc.o cmll_cbc.o
MODES_OBJ     =
ENGINES_OBJ   =
PROCESSOR     =
RANLIB        =/usr/bin/ranlib
ARFLAGS       =
PERL          =/opt/local/bin/perl5
THIRTY_TWO_BIT mode
BN_LLONG mode
RC4_CHUNK is undefined
...
```

Comment: Wow it worked! Thanks so much for all the help! A definite best answer on the internet!

Comment: Just as a side question though, I am still a little confused as to why the ./Configure is included in the INSTALL doc as a way to cross compile. It says when cross compiling to use ./Configure <architecture> instead of ./config. If it is a procedural violation why is this an option?

Comment: @Grindlemire - I'm not sure about `INSTALL` with the FIPS gear. Looking at the files from `openssl-fips-2.0.5`, I don't see an `INSTALL`. I do see a `README.FIPS`, but it states to visit `http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips`.

Answer (score 1):

Henry Unger on the [OpenSSL mailing list](http://marc.info/?l=openssl-users&m=140493597310483&w=2) shared the following:

> To build a 32-bit OpenSSL library on 32-bit or 64-bit Solaris 10 using
>   gcc, we do:
>
> ```
> export MACHINE=x86
> export CC='gcc -m32'
> ```

After exporting `CC` and `MACHINE`, run `config`.

Comment: When it tries to compile using this method, it does not recognize the machine. Specifically it says:

    This system (solaris64-x86_64-gcc -m32) is not supported. See file INSTALL for details.

I believe the problem lies in that it is identifying my computer as a 64 bit machine when I am trying to compile 32 bit code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I fixed it  *I think*

Previously I was using this command:

```
./config fipscanisterbuild
```

and I had tried this command as well

```
./Configure solaris-x86-gcc
```

I was able to force the configure to create a 32 bit binary with the correct dependencies by using this command:

```
./Configure solaris-x86-gcc fipscanisterbuild
```

Similar to what jww said, this command forces the Configure to identify the computer as a solaris-x86 machine compiling on gcc. The difference is that I am not leaving the Configure to decide what architecture the machine is and adding a flag to show the compiler what I am wanting, instead I am making it use the solaris-x86-gcc.

Comment: I believe `./Configure solaris-x86-gcc fipscanisterbuild` is a procedural violation. If you look at the [OpenSSL FIPS 140-2 Security Policy v 2.0.7](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140sp/140sp1747.pdf), *Appendix A, Installation and Usage Guidance* (p. 27), the command sets are `./config` or `./config no-asm`. You have to execute one or the other. However, the environment (`MACHINE` and `SYSTEM`) is *not* sequestered as part of the FIPS 140-2 process, so you are free to modify them. Hence the reason for the knob turning on them.

Comment: Steve Marquess of the OpenSSL Foundation is much more versed in FIPS 140-2 policy. He frequently talks with Dr. Easter (Dr. Easter runs the FIPS 140 program at NIST). You might want to engage him. His email address is marquess@opensslfoundation.com. You can also reach him through [OpenSSL Software Foundation Contact Info](http://opensslfoundation.com/contact.html). The Adamstown address is his office.

Comment: Ok will do, however in the INSTALL doc in the openssl-fips directory it does say that if you are cross-compiling or ./config misidentifies your compile you should use ./Configure and specify the compiler yourself.